# Performing PCA in R with many NAs

Tags: r, pca, missing-data

I have a large dataset of 10 variables and 12,000 observations, coming from 3 types of distinct systems (200 from small ponds, 600 from rivers and 11200 from lakes). I have a lot of NAs in my dataframe but still want to perform a PCA to see how different the systems are, using only the last 4 columns of my dataframe (the first columns being descriptive of the sites, the last four being chemical data).

Any cue to ways to deal with that ?

Comment: Hi, the nature of this question seems more statistical. I suggest you to post it on Cross Validated rather than here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem of the missing value in different way. 
Below I'm going to illustrate them.

You should use the mean of the variable that includes NA values or impute the missing values with a linear regression.

You should use `missMDA` and then `FactoMineR` or the `pcaMethods`.
Below an example.

```
library(missMDA)
nPCs <- estim_ncpPCA(VIM::sleep)

Output 
nPCS$ncp
    3

completed_sleep <- imputePCA(VIM::sleep, ncp = nPCs$ncp, scale = TRUE)
PCA(completed_sleep$completeObs)
```

The other example is:

```
library(pcaMethods)
sleep_pca_methods <- pca(sleep, nPcs=2, method="ppca", center = TRUE)
imp_air_pcamethods <- completeObs(sleep_pca_methods)
```

If you'd like to deep the `PCA` or the factoMiner package you should visit its website http://factominer.free.fr/